# Why do I find extra reference objects to the linked list?

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I've been working on the exercise to better understand Linked List.

My output is:
***DISPALY NAMES 
Miki
null
Arek
null
Magi
null

---

Problem: display nulls between names.

Tried to do: Wrote bunch of print statements and it looks like is adding extra Name reference object to the list. I was trying to find error in the add method but logically everything fines for me.

I am not allowed to use LinkedList API.

Thank you for your help.

```
<pre> <code>
public class NameTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NameList<Name> n = new NameList<Name>();
    Name n1 = new Name(1,"Miki");
    Name n2 = new Name(2, "Arek");
    Name n3 = new Name(3, "Magi");

    n.addName(n1);
            n.addName(n2);
            n.addName(n3);
    n.displayNames();
    System.out.println("*******************\n");
     }
}

public class Name {

private int nameId;
private String firstName;   
private Name next;

public Name() { }

public Name(int nameId, String firstName) {
    super();
    this.nameId = nameId;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.next = new Name();
}

public int getNameId() {
    return nameId;
}

public void setNameId(int nameId) {
    this.nameId = nameId;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public Name getNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setNext(Name next) {
    this.next = next;
}   
}

public class NameList<T extends Name> {

private T head;
private int value;

public NameList() {
    head = null;
    value = 0;
}

public T getHead() {
    return head;
}

public void setHead(T head) {
    this.head = head;
}

public void addName(T name) { 
    if(head == null) {
        setHead(name);
        value++;
    }
    else {      
        T curr = getHead();
        while(curr.getNext() != null) {
            curr = (T) curr.getNext();
        }
        curr.setNext(name);
        value++;
    }
}

public void displayNames() {
    System.out.println("***DISPLAY NAMES ");
    T curr = getHead();

    while(curr.getNext() != null ) {
        System.out.println(curr.getFirstName());
        curr = (T) curr.getNext();
    }
    if(curr.getNext() == null) {
        System.out.println(curr.getFirstName());
    }
}
```

Instance variable next in the class name should be like this: private Name next; I am sorry for confusion. I made correction in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line.

```
this.next = new Name();
```

You're adding a new "empty object" onto the back of every `Name` that you add.  Remove it and you'll get the desired result.  (I assume you also have `Name extends Employee` in there somewhere, otherwise this doesn't compile).

Comment: Thank you for advice. Instance variable next in the class name should be like this: private Name next; I am sorry for the confusion. I made correction in the code above. Maybe it is funny question but how should I instantiate "next" in overloaded constructor? I have just one idea but I am noy sure if it is correct next = null;

Comment: You could write `next = null;` but you don't need to.  Instance variables of object type always default to null.